# how to read many columns from excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I want to read the data in like 162 rows from excel, I tried this code but I couldn't figure out a way to make it in a loop

```
import xlrd
file_location = "dec_DB.xlsx"

   workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

x = []

for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
    x.append(sheet.cell(rownum, 3))
```

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `excel`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the columns you want from an excel sheet easily in one line with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel(io = "/Users/atheeralzaydi/Desktop/KACST/DB/dec_DB.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1", usecols = [1,2,3,12,34,100])
```

`x` will be a pandas DataFrame.

**EDIT:**

To read the first 162 rows (+1 including the header -- the row that includes the column names), instead of the parameter `usecols`, use the parameter `nrows`:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel(io = "/Users/atheeralzaydi/Desktop/KACST/DB/dec_DB.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1", nrows = 162)
```

To import specific rows and not the first `m` rows, use the parameter `skiprows`.

To import the entire sheet, simply omit these parameters and all rows will be imported.

More info on `read_excel` [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: I'm sorry I meant rows, does this code work with rows?

Comment: @atheer Do you want to read the first 162 rows?